# Best practices for factory classes with C# dependency injection?

Tags: c#, unity-container, factory

I'm using unity for dependency injection and currently I have a lot of classes that just have properties and are passed around a lot, kind of like this:

```
public class TickerApiAddress
{
    public string CoinTicker { get; set; }
    public string ApiAddress { get; set; }
    public double Notional { get; set; }
}
```

Instead of creating these hard objects everywhere I would like to use a kind of factory class that builds the object for me so that later I can mock the returns from the factory class in unit tests.

```
ITickerApiAddress ticker = _tickerApiAddressFactory.Create(cointicker, apiaddress, notional);
```

Is there any best practice for factories like this with dependency injection? I've done some research and I can't seem to find many examples where people have done this using DI. Should I be making some wrapper around ParameterInfo and using this?

Comment: Hi! What problem are you trying to solve using factories here? If the only problem is to provide arguments, unity allow to bind them directly, like in answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663683/unitycontainer-how-to-register-a-class-constructor-with-parameters#15671720
This is better solution as far as you don't new to write factory. Please correct me If I understand you wrong.

Comment: Anyway questions about best practices are off-topic here as they are quite opinion-based.

Comment: @Drag13 Thanks! Exactly what i'm wanting to be able to do is inject the factory class via the constructor so I can mock the objects being created easily in unit tests. I'm still quite new to Unity so not completely sure on the conventions for creating these kind of hard objects.

Comment: If the only idea is to provide mocks, you don't need  factory at all. All you need is to create interface of the desired class, register it with unity, and consume inside the constructor. Do you need an example?

Comment: @Drag13 Registering it with the container and adding it in on the constructor is okay for situations where I only need one of those object per class. But I need multiple different instances of that object. I like the suggestion more to use those ParameterOverrides from your link and i'd create them in a separate class. Before I close the post, do you know if there is any advantage for using reflection to do this?

Comment: DI containers use reflection, so feel free to use. But you should remember that reflection can cause performance hit so do this wisely.